# Is PrototypeScript.js necessary for Richfaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, prototype, richfaces

Our site currently uses Richfaces 3.3.3 and JSF 2.
There are various native custom javscript functions scattered about the site.

I'm looking to clean it all up and implement a reusable set of custom libraries that will use the jQuery javascript framework.

There is currently no custom code using custom Prototype on our site.

What I'm wondering is:
Can I remove the prototype file completely? 
It currently takes up 96kb and 78ms to load.
3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.PrototypeScript.xhtml

Or is it necessary in order for some of the Richfaces components to work correctly?

If I can remove it, how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is necessary. Richfaces uses jQuery too, so if you instruct Richfaces to load jQuery on all pages (see [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#ScriptsandStylesLoadStrategy) on how to do it), you can use jQuery. Another way is to use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

List of component dependencies is in `richfaces-ui-XXX.jar\META-INF\richfaces.component-dependencies.xml`, if you don't use any component that depends on prototype (only a slim chance), you may remove prototype (see the linked documentation on how).

In Richfaces 4.0 prototype is removed in favor of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Adam...looks like its staying in so until we upgrade to 4!